# PZ - Car tire wheel friction

Tags: project-zomboid

So your tires have value, wheel friction.

You can do 2 things with tires:
- Inflate
- Deflate

[image]

**What is optimal wheel friction?**

Should you go for as high as possible? Or have it around 1.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflating a tire will reduce wheel friction and brake force. Deflating the tires will do the opposite. Wheel condition will do the same thing as deflating the tires. 1.0 wheel friction is optimal.